# Why do some C programs work in debug but not in release?

Tags: c, debugging, crash, release, codeblocks

Ok,

So I am stuck here. I have code for a program that systematically executes people standing in a circle based off an algorithm, but I am having a problem with it crashing in release mode. My code runs fine if I run it using the debugger (codeblocks), but if I don't it crashes. I looked around online, and the only thing I am finding is unintialized variables, but I tried immediately setting values for my variables at declaration and it didn't fix the problem.

If anyone can see what my problem is, I would greatly appreciate help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

// if the program does not work, please run in debugger mode. It will work.

void remove_person(int** array, int arraySize, int position)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
        printf("%d ", (*array)[i]);
    printf("\n");

    int* temp = malloc((arraySize - 1) * sizeof(int)); // create temporary array smaller by one element

    memmove(temp,*array,(position+1)*sizeof(int)); // copy entire array before position

    memmove(temp+position,(*array)+(position+1),(arraySize - position)*sizeof(int)); // copy entire array after postion

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; ++i)
        printf("%d ", (temp)[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free (*array);
    *array = temp;
}


int kill(int** a, int n)
{
    int pos = 0;
    int round = 1;
    while(n > 1)
    {
        pos = pos + 2 - (round % 2);

        while(pos >= n)
            pos = pos - n;

        remove_person(a,n,pos);
        n--;

        while(pos >= n)
            pos = pos - n;
        round++;
    }
    return *a[0];
}

void main()
{
    int n, survivor, i;
    int* people;

    printf("Enter number of people for Russian Roulette: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    people = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        people[i] = i;
    }

    survivor  = kill(&people, n);
    printf("The survivor is person #%d\n", survivor);
}
```

Comment: `void main` is non-standard.

Comment: Don't you think that a simple list will be pretty than this solution? To remove element from list you just need to `free()` it and modify a `next` pointer of previous element.

Comment: @chris: recommended reading: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/legality-of-void-main.html. tl;dr: `void main()` is allowed by the C99 standard in an implementation-defined manner.

Comment: @nneonneo, Shame about [this](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main), then. Perhaps it was focusing on an earlier standard.

Comment: @chris: Stroustrup **is wrong**. Read the spec: http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html. Pay attention to the line "or equivalent; or in *some other implementation-defined manner.*"

Comment: @nneonneo, Yes, I saw. I have a draft of the C11 standard. That's why I said it was a shame, whether it's just not updated, or wrong from the start.

Comment: Yeah, even C11 allows for `void main`. I don't know how Stroustrup (who should be, by all means, a master of specifications) missed this. I believe `void main` has been allowed since C89. (Also, the standard basically allows for any return type at all, even stupid things like `float main` or `struct foo main`).

Comment: As for your code you have several mistakes: in `remove_person` you don't check for `position < arraySize`, in first `memmove` you copy one extra number (make 's/(position+1)/position/'), the same thing you're doing in second `memmove` (make 's/(arraySize - position)/(arraySize - position -1)/'). In debug mode it seems that memory allocates by big blocks, that's why you didn't get segfaults.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: `remove_person` doesn't need to check `position < arraySize` because `kill` guarantees it.

Comment: @nneonneo, but as for `memmove`, I was right. OOps. I didn't see your answer.

Answer (score 7):

The basic answer to the title question ("Why do some C programs work in debug but not in release?") is "*when they invoke undefined behaviour*".

Here, in

```
memmove(temp,*array,(position+1)*sizeof(int)); // copy entire array before position

memmove(temp+position,(*array)+(position+1),(arraySize - position)*sizeof(int)); // copy entire array after postion
```

you copy too much. To see why, observe that the first `memmove` copies to `temp[0]`, `temp[1]`, ..., `temp[position]`, and the second copies to `temp[position]`, `temp[position+1]`, ..., `temp[position+arraySize-position-1] = temp[arraySize-1]` (note the overlap at `temp[position]`). But `temp` only has space for `arraySize-1` elements -- you copied one more than it was allowed to hold, so you get **undefined behaviour**.

It probably works in debug but not release mode because the heap is laid out differently (debug-mode allocators may pad the allocations with extra space to catch bugs like this when running under a debugger or profiler).

Answer (score 0):

The program segfaults if I enter 4 (or even numbers higher than 4) as input, but I won't go into the code to see why that happens.

Apart from that the program works just fine, the problem is that you don't see the output because I think you run it on windows.

That being said you should add something like `scanf("%d", &n);` at the end or run `cmd.exe`, go to the directory that holds the executable and run it from there.